# How to convert bytes in a string to integers? Python

Tags: python

I want to get a list of ints representing the bytes in a string.

Comment: If you don't mean ASCII values (as you wrote in a comment below), what *do* you mean?

Comment: Can you give an example of what the string looks like if you are not interested in the ascii values?

Comment: Are you trying to convert string to int - in that case, see my answer - and somebody give me a MindReader badge ;)

Comment: Shall we bet on it (I doubt that's what he wants)? Hey, feature request for meta: Bet rep points on what a question means, winner takes all.

Comment: @Tim In that case, another option that I can think of is to convert `"00010100"` to 20 and so on - who wanna bet on that ;-)

Comment: I thought I didnt want ASCII values but they result to be what I was looking for :) Sorry. The root of my confusion was that I was using some non alphabetic chars and I didnt realize that the values were actually ascii values.

Answer (score 14):

One option for Python 2.6 and later is to use a [`bytearray`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#bytearray):

```
>>> b = bytearray('hello')
>>> b[0]
104
>>> b[1]
101
>>> list(b)
[104, 101, 108, 108, 111]
```

For Python 3.x you'd need a [`bytes`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#bytes) object rather than a string in any case and so could just do this:

```
>>> b = b'hello'
>>> list(b)
[104, 101, 108, 108, 111]
```

Comment: To clarify for the OP, these values *are* the ascii values.

Answer (score 7):

Do you mean the ascii values?

```
nums = [ord(c) for c in mystring]
```

or

```
nums = []
for chr in mystring:
    nums.append(ord(chr))
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you mean a string of bytes, for example received over the net, representing a couple of integer values?

In that case you can "unpack" the string into the integer values by using unpack() and specifying "i" for integer as the format string.

See:
http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html